# Correct path from js to assets/images path in rails app

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku

How to correctly write path to 'assets/images/' inside a `js.erb` file? I am doing:

```html
icon: createImage('assets/'+img),
```

interestingly, this works in localhost, but not in heroku.
After searching in stackoveflow I try this:

```html
icon: createImage('<%= asset_path(img) %>'),
```

I guess this one should help me. But I cannot pass img to `asset_path`.

Note: I am doing it in `assets/javascript/map/gmap.js.erb`

EDIT: I have found in rails guides that the files in app/assets are never served directly in production. So now i know why it isn't working in production.
 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
icon: createImage('<%= image_tag(img) %>')
```

Especially if you are running Rails 3.1+ and using the Asset Pipeline, you want to use Rails helpers to specify files, not hard coded file paths.  This should look for the `img` file in `/assets` as described [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag).

Comment: how to pass img to image_tag, i can not just pas it to erb, since it is declared in js.

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand that.  There is no way to do that directly - the server side code gets evaluated first (.erb), then the Javascript (.js).  You probably need to explain a bit more about your use case in your post.  There might be a better overall approach.  I can delete this answer if you want so that this shows up with no answers again.

Comment: ok, I understood. The way i solved this is just hardcoding my image paths into asset_path. Thanks i have only 5 of them.